# Interface Builder XIB Compiler error

Tags: interface-builder, xcode4.4

I get this error message when connecting two UISwipeGestureRecognizers to a single view in my project inside of a XIB file (though not in a new project, curiously).  Anybody know what this error means?  It is a compile error, not a runtime error.  I'm using Xcode 4.4 (this error doesn't happen on Xcode 4.5 actually).  This is an error from inside interface builder.

> Assertion failure in -[IBCocoaTouchToolObjectPackage connectionsByProcessingConnections:], /SourceCache/IBSimulatorComponents/IBSimulatorComponents-223/IBCocoaTouchTool/IBCocoaTouchToolObjectPackage.m:1132012-08-03 16:52:01.428 Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool[5646:11903] Exception producing nib: Mismatched addsContentToExistingCollection value for the coalescing outlet connection & one of its fragments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this occurs because Interface Builder allows your outlets to get into an inconsistent state. It's a logic bug in Interface Builder that manifests as a run-time exception in the `ibtool` compiler. I was able to work around it by disconnecting the outlets and outlet collections I had recently created, and then rewiring them.

Comment: Interestingly enough, I also saw this error immediately after wiring up two `UISwipeGestureRecognizer`s, though I can hardly see how such an error would be specifically caused by that class.

Comment: Unfortunately for me, unwiring and rewiring them just causes the error again.  I will try disconnecting all the connections and rewiring them when I get back to the project.

Comment: Well, randomly disconnecting and reconnecting some of the connections made it work...so I guess this is the correct answer lol.

Comment: Yeah, it's a pity that we sometimes have to apply voodoo to get our tools working, but that's the state of things on the Xcode front...

Comment: Just had this problem. Random unwiring and rewiring is the solution. My preferred solution is to not use IB, but alas, other people's code.

Answer (score 0):

I was actually able to get rid of the error by deleting the entire Panel in the XIB, and then just undoing the delete. Clean + Build and the error was gone. Not sure if that will work for others as well.