# Interface Builder XIB compiler error on Xcode 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode8, xcode9

After switching to Xcode 9 then back to Xcode 8, my build is failing and I'm getting this error. I'm not getting any error on Xcode 9 though.

Note: I've already checked :[Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11791710/interface-builder-xib-compiler-error) and [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23924536/xcode-interface-builder-xib-compiler-error), however it's not working.

Why am I getting this error?

> BasketTotalView.xib: Internal error. Please file a bug at bugreport.apple.com and attach "/var/folders/dg/_yf1yfd15svdj48mrrlws5vw0000gp/T/IB-agent-diagnostics_2017-08-18_10-08-35_271000".

Comment: clean the derived data and run once

Comment: Did you file the bug?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
Click on your .XIB file 

From Right side bar select "Show the file Inspector"

Go to "Interface Builder Document" section.

In "Open In" dropdown select Xcode 8.

Clear derived data, Build and Run. 

May this help you.
```

Comment: Couldn't find `Show the file Inspector` option. Simple DerivedData clean worked

Comment: yep deleting derived data worked for me too - cracking error message thanks Apple...

Comment: Confirmed, just derived data.

Comment: restarted the system, waited for some time, cleaned derived data and rebuilt  worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

I have solved this issue by following below steps:

```
1. cmd + shift + k
2. cmd + option + shift + k
3. Restart Xcode
4. Restart your pc.
```

Hope this will also works for you.
Thanks!

Comment: 5. Turn off the power of the city you live in. 6. Pay a hitman to harass Apple CEO for the bullshit IDE that they develop. Sorry for the off-topic message but I need to discharge my frustration somewhere. I often think that Apple devs never use XCode for their development, that's how crapy new Xcode releases are.

Comment: I've had this happen a few times. Both answers have worked for me in separate cases. Hard to say what warrants a restart but worth trying all the options listed in both answers.

Comment: @danypata LOLOLOLOL you are getting the same with me

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the .xib file in the project wasn't linked correctly to a file in Finder, and it was dimmed a bit. After linking the file, it worked fine without any errors.

The file can be linked by selecting it, and then from the file inspector, select the folder icon front the full path label, and locate the file.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, none of the options above helped cause my problem wasn't in the DerivedData. I clicked on the arrow on the right side of the Interface Builder and it took me to a subfolder system inside */private/var/folders/*

[This is the arrow that takes you to the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAgiG.png)

I've cleaned it and rebooted the Mac. It worked! I followed this tutorial:

[Can I delete files or folders from /private/var/folders/?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/176374)

Some will say that just the reboot is enough to clean the folder but I've cleaned it anyway.